# Move files that are being executed from batch file

Tags: batch-file, drag-and-drop

First of all, it's my first time around here, so tell me if anything is wrong :D

This is the actual situation: I have some tasks running more or less constantly (scheduled tasks from Windows Task Scheduler) that are in a live environment, while I develop in a dev environment. When I want to launch updates to live, what I usually do is "Drag and drop" the current files in the live environment to a backup folder. This way, the tasks that were running, keep running in the new backup folder. At this point, I copy the updated files to the live folder. Therefore, the next time the tasks are executed, they will be already updated.

But it turns out to be kind of annoying each time I want to include new things, so I wanted to have a little batch script that does all of this automatically. The thing is that it seems impossible to do the "Drag and drop" function from batch.

I have tried using the usual "move" function, creating some symbolic links, using other copying tools such as Robocopy. But none of them have had success. I always get some error due to my tasks being executed all the time.

Is there a way around this problem? Mainly, is it possible to reproduce the "drag and drop" functionality from a batch script or similar?

Thank you very much!

Comment: command line `copy` or `xcopy`  using wildcards in the file name using the same scheduled task to check for updates before it runs the main executable?

Comment: "I always get some error due to my tasks being executed all the time." You mean the files are locked? I'm not sure why this would be different for a shell drag-and-drop, unless it has logic to wait for them to become free, or more specific lock settings on open.

Comment: The problem for the copy functions is that later you would have to delete them from the live folder and this can't be achieved because they are being used. About what Rup asked, I don't think so. It's just that the tasks are running. So somehow the functions I have tried in shell always do some kind of copy and delete, which doesn't work. On the other hand, dragging and dropping from the interface keeps the current tasks executing at the new place somehow.

Comment: Good that you took the [tour], now go read [Ask], and [MCVE]. If you're not going post some code you are having problems with, then try asking your question on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'm working out a code that reproduces the problem!